# lag() and lead() sql server function to select data from diff table

Tags: sql-server, lag, lead

I need help to be able to do the following:

*MainTable* has

```
ID (Primary Key)
DATE_TIME
STATE
```

*SubTable* has

```
ID (Primary Key)
DATE_TIME
LINE1
```

When `MainTable.STATE` value changes from 100 to 200, I want to select `SubTable.Line1` value where `MainTable.DATE_TIME = SubTable.DATE_TIME`

It seems that either `LAG()` or `LEAD()` function can detects this transition of data in `MainTable.STATE` field.

How can do this with SQL statement using `LAG()` or `LEAD()` function?

***Thanks for all the quick responses. Since MainTable.STATE value could be anything, I can't include its value in the sql stmt.***

Comment: It may be helpful to consider that the LAG and LEAD functions only work with SQL Server 2012, otherwise you have to write code to simulate this action.

Comment: What do you mean *could be anything*?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT Line1
FROM SubTable s
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DATE_TIME, State, LAG(State) OVER(ORDER BY DATE_TIME) as LastState
    FROM MainTable 
)
m
ON s.DATE_TIME = m.DATE_TIME
WHERE State = 200
AND LastState = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, you can do something like this:

```
select Line1
  from (
select T1.[Id] as T1Id,
       T1.[Key] as T1Key,
       T1.[State] as T1State,
       T2.[Id] as T2Id,
       T2.[FKey] as T2Key,
       T2.[Line] as T2Line1,
       lag(T1.[State], 1, 100) OVER (order by T1.[Id]) as PriorState
  from T1
       left outer join T2 on T1.[Key] = T2.FKey
) as Data
 where [T1State] <> PriorState
   and [T1State] = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN State = 200 AND LAG(State) OVER(ORDER BY ID) = 100 
               THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Line1 FROM SubTable WHERE DATE_TIME = m.DATE_TIME) END 
FROM MainTable m
```